# WebDriverException: unknown error: document.getBoxObjectFor is not a function using Selenium with ChromeDriver and Chrome through Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

On clicking an element in chrome browser in selenium-testng:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: document.getBoxObjectFor is not a function
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

is displayed as error

I tried:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(element));
```

Code trial:

```
public void clickHERE(String deal) throws Throwable
{   
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(HERE)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(enterDeal)).sendKeys(deal);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(searchButtonDCP)).click();
    scrollToElement(driver, nextTabDealInfo);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(nextTabDealInfo)).click();
}
```

For first line of code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(HERE)).click();
```

in above function, driver should click and navigate to next page.

Comment: Hi shivam, welcome to Stack Overflow! It is unclear what you're asking. Please read the article on [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: document.getBoxObjectFor is not a function
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to communicate with the *WebBrowser* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.42*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.42*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v68-70**

- You are using *chrome=73.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.46*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v71-73**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.42* and the *Chrome Browser v73.0*

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.46**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v71-73*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.46 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.